# what is the term for someone who likes to be the center of attention, by talking about himself and his greatness

Tags: meaning, word-request

I am not sure if it's duplicate, but what is the term for someone who likes to be the center of attention by talking about himself and greatness (and not sure about the word, but dislikes and fails what people say or do).

Example: A guy with some people, he talks most of the time and does not always give people a chance to talk, he likes it when people ask him questions or give him advice, and when he talks, he speaks about the great things he did (I traveled to Paris with girls and spent nights at. . .) and if people talk about what they did he start to minimize that (oh I can do that its simple. . .)

What is the term for this? I am not looking for *ego* or *selfish*.

Comment: I might call him a *blowhard*.

Comment: I fixed your grammar, mostly. Please reread your post. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168752/is-there-a-less-colloquial-word-noun-or-adjective-to-describe-an-attention-wh) on the ELU.se which is a little similar to this.

While there is no single word that completely covers all of the things you mention, this might be the closest you'll get. The [top answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/168770) on that question suggests [**ostentatious**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ostentatious).

> marked by or fond of conspicuous or vainglorious and sometimes pretentious display

Comment: 'ostentatious' might cover the 2nd attribute you mention "...he speak about the great things he did..." (although native English speakers would not use it like that, preferring to use boast or something similar) but it in no way describes either the 1st or 3rd attributes. Think carefully before using ostentatious to describe that sort of person.

Answer (score 2):

A bore. Or you could say "They are full of themselves" or that "they like to belittle other's accomplishments".

Comment: I am searching for a spefic term,  bore not specific ..from google bore :(of an athlete or racehorse) push another competitor out of the way.

Comment: Bore (noun) - someone who talks too much about boring subjects (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bore_1). There is no single word in English that covers everything you've described, because you have described multiple different behaviours: Someone who talks about themselves, someone who boasts about what they have done and someone who belittles other people accomplishments. A poor conversationalist may posses any or all of these attributes.

Comment: In the UK, we're more likely to say that someone is 'a dreadful conversationalist' and then go on to explain why.

Answer (score 2):

Narcissist.

> Narcissism is the pursuit of gratification from vanity or egotistic admiration of one's own attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of these is what you're looking for: conceited, big-headed, pompous, smug.

And a quote from "Use the right word"

> Boastful and vainglorious concentrate on this last possibility of
>   egotistical, both referring to self-praise and attention-seeking in
>   public. Boastful emphasizes unsubtle and even boorish public displays
>   of vocal self-approval: after a few drinks, he always became boastful
>   about his wartime activities. Vainglorious focuses more exclusively on
>   hollow show, boastful self-praise, but conspicuous displays of status
>   symbols are often involves: vainglorious dowagers dripping minks and
>   diamonds.

I really like this book (I found a .bgl for GoldenDict on internet). Usually words that are used in explanations are difficult and not common, but they clearly convey the sense of every single word and clarify every single nuance nuances you are curious about.

Answer (score 0):

In the states we say, "hogging the limelight" ( or spotlight) so I like to say that such a person is a "limelight hog."

Answer (score 0):

"Pretentious" adjective
adjective: pretentious

> attempting to impress by affecting greater importance, talent, culture, etc., than is actually possessed.

Comment: Please link to the source of the quoted material.

Answer (score -1):

I'm quite astounded to see that no one mentioned the word that I constantly use when I refer myself to somebody.

> One who seeks attention is: Attentiomonger;
>
> And the habit/ characteristic is called: Attentionmongerism.

Comment: I've never heard people use that phrase. It may or may not be a valid word, but nobody uses that extensively.

Comment: That coinage means someone who *sells* attention and would be inappropriate for someone who *seeks* attention.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the word means attention seeking, otherwise, it's up to you to use it or not!!